# Euler's Refutation of Fermat's Conjecture

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Fermat postulated that all numbers of the form $$2^{2^n}+1$$ are prime (where n = any integer). Then Euler came along with a rather ingenious proof that this was not, in fact the case. I came across this while reading William Dunham's *Journey Through Genius,* Chapter 10.

Here's the gist of what I get so far (of how Euler refuted Fermat's above suggestion):

**Theorem A:** If $a$ is an even number, and $p$ is prime that does not factor evenly into $a$ (but is a factor of $a+1$), then $p = 2k+1$ for an integer $k$.

So far so good, and Dunham discusses the proof for this theorem, but I'm going to guess that you mathematicians here are familiar with this.

Next we move onto Theorem B.

**Theorem B:** If $a$ is an even number and p is a prime (not a factor of $a$), and $p$ goes evenly into $a^2+1$, then for an integer $k$, $p = 4k+1$, but $p$ cannot equal $4k+3$.

Here's how this works:

1. Firstly, $a$ is even, so $a^2$ is also even. Using Theorem A, it becomes obvious that any prime factor of $a^2+1$ is odd. Ergo, $p$ is odd (so it's not 2).
2. If we divide $p$ by 4, then $p$ can equal either $4k+1$ or $4k+3$.
3. Since $p$ is a divisor of $a^2+1$, p also divides evenly into the product ($a^2+1$)($a^{4k}-a^{4k-2}+a^{4k-4}...+a^4-a^2+1$). Algebraic manipulation shows that this product equals $a^{4k+2}+1$.

And this is where I'm confused. Where on earth does Dunham pull ($a^{4k}-a^{4k-2}+a^{4k-4}...+a^4-a^2+1$) from? No explanation is offered on his part, so any enlightenment on this would be appreciated.

**More Details**
As stated earlier, if we divide $p$ by 4, then $p$ can equal either $4k+1$ or $4k+3$ (which is pretty clear if you plug in values for $k$). We want to demonstrate that $k$ can only equal $4k+1$, and we do this by proof by contradiction (assume $p=4k+3$). Why do we want to do this? Well, we want to know the form of $p$ so we can figure out the potential factors of $2^{32}+1$, which Fermat postulated was prime.

Since $p$ is not a divisor of $a$ (by hypothesis), Fermat's little theorem would suggest that $p$ goes nicely into $a^{p-1}-1=a^{{4k+3}-1}-1=a^{4k+2}-1$.

Says Dunham (p. 231):

"On the other hand, we have assumed that $p$ is a divisor of $a^2+1$, and consequently $p$ is also a divisor of the product ($a^2+1$)($a^{4k}-a^{4k-2}+a^{4k-4}...+a^4-a^2+1$)."

Since this product equals $a^{4k+2}+1$, and since $p$ goes evenly into both $a^{4k+2}+1$ and $a^{4k+2}-1$, $p$ is a divisor of ($a^{4k+2}+1$)-($a^{4k+2}-1$) = 2, but this cannot be true since $p$ is an odd prime. Ergo, $p$ is not of the form $p=4k+3$.

Let me know if you all need more details and stuff.

Comment: First of all the third statement seems to be fase; in stead
$$(a^2+1)(a^{4k}-a^{4k-2}+a^{4k-4}+\ldots+a^4-a^2+1)=a^{4k+2}+1.$$
Moreover te proof does not seem to be finished. Could you post the rest of the proof? This may clarify Dunhams reason to look at this product.

Comment: Woops, you're right that it equals $a^{4k+2}+1$. I've edited the OP to reflect this. Will post rest of proof shortly.

Comment: Fermat statement was about the integers $2^{2^n}+1$.

Comment: You are correct of course -- thanks for the catch. Edited.

Comment: There are actually very simple methods to prove Theorem B (and the entire claim) if you are willing to take on board modular arithmetic and quadratic residues.

Comment: I don't really understand the theorem A: you're basically saying that if $p$ divides some odd number, then $p$ is odd? Calling this a theorem seems like a bit of stretch, and the wording is awkward. Am I misuderstanding something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me rephrase the argument, and put the contradiction in another place:

Let $a$ be an even integer, and let $p$ be a prime dividing $a^2+1$. Then $p$ is odd because $a^2+1$ is odd, so $p$ has remainder $1$ or $3$ after division by $4$, that is, either $p=4k+1$ or $p=4k+3$ for some integer $k$.

Suppose towards a contradiction that $p=4k+3$ for some integer $k$. By Fermat's little theorem we know that $p$ divides the number
$$a^{p-1}-1 = a^{4k+2}-1,$$
and it is clear that $p$ does not divide $2$. It follows that $p$ does not divide $a^{4k+2}+1$. By assumption $p$ divides $a^2+1$, and $a^2+1$ in turn divides $a^{4k+2}+1$. But then $p$ divides $a^{4k+2}+1$, a contradiction.

To see that $a^2+1$ divides $a^{4k+2}+1$, one can write out the multiplication
$$(a^2+1)(a^{4k}-a^{4k-2}+a^{4k-4}+\ldots+a^4-a^2+1).$$
This may seem like magic, but with the use of some abstract algebra one can quickly see that $a^2+1$ must divide $a^{4k+2}+1$, without having to figure out how many times $a^2+1$ fits into $a^{4k+2}+1$ exactly. Once you know that one divides the other, you can apply (for example) Euclid's algorithm to find precisely how many times $a^2+1$ fits in $a^{4k+2}+1$. In this way you may find the big and nasty expression $a^{4k}-a^{4k-2}+a^{4k-4}+\ldots+a^4-a^2+1$, but the only purpose of this expression in the proof is to show that $a^2+1$ divides $a^{4k+2}+1$.

---

It is worth noting that a bit of abstract algebra allows for a much shorter proof of Theorem B. It requires only some modular arithmetic and group theory:

Let $p$ be an odd prime dividing $a^2+1$, so that $a^2\equiv-1\pmod{p}$. Then $a$ has order $4$ in $(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$, hence $4$ divides the order of $(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$, which is $p-1$. This shows that $p=4k+1$ for some $k\in\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: Beautiful. I experienced the "ahha!" moment quite nicely. Thanks -- this really made sense.